# Issue with PHP variable when fetched from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have a variable like "Doctor and Surgical" I take this value from Mysql database and store it in a variable. When I echo this variable it gives me only "Doctor" 
Can anyone tell me how can I take the above value retrieved from Mysql as an entire variable...

EDIT

Please find the code below

```
query.php
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<select name="cat">
<?php
$sql="select distinct Category from tbl_1 order by Category asc";
$query=mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

 echo "<option value=".$row[Category].">".$row[Category]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<select name="station">
<?php
$sql_1="select distinct Station from tbl_1 order by Station asc";
$query_1=mysql_query($sql_1);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_1))
{

echo "<option value=".$row[Station].">".$row[Station]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input name="C" type="submit" />
</form>



process.php

$myValue =$_POST['cat'];
$myStation=$_POST['station'];

echo $myValue;
echo "<br/>";
echo $myStation;

$mySqlStm ="SELECT Name FROM tbl_1 WHERE Category='$myValue' and Station='$myStation'";

$result2 = mysql_query($mySqlStm) or die("Error:mysql_error()"); 

if(mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0){ 
echo("<br/>no records found"); 
} 
ELSE 
{ 
echo "<table border='1'>"; 

//ECHO THE RECORDS FETCHED
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
{ 
echo "<tr>"; 

echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"; 
}}
```

Here when I echo $myValue it gives me "Doctor" instead of "Doctor and Surgeon" 
I need "Doctor and Surgeon as an entire variable.

Comment: can you show some of your code please?

Comment: yea, you can't expect any help with just that description

Comment: Please don't vote to close. The user is clearly new here, and needs some assistance understanding how to ask an appropriate question. @user501582 Please provide the code you're having issues with.

Comment: "member for  1 year, 6 months" funny definition of *new* you have

Comment: @Dagon I'm going based on the reputation. He's asked four questions over that time - let's be patient.

Comment: Too bad @user is not listening... I really wanted to dig into this one, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the value properly:

```
 echo "<option value='".$row[Category]."'>".$row[Category]."</option>";
```

With your current code, if you look at the source you will probably see something like this:

```
 <option value=Some Category>Some Category</option>
```

But with proper quotation you'll see the correct value.

Comment: To my mind, `echo '<option value="'.$row[Category].'">'.$row[Category].'</option>';` is clearer.

Comment: @JMCCreative It worked :) Thanks I don't understand the quotations much in PHP. I am very new to the language... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this without having to concatenate:

```
echo "<option value='{$row[Category]}'>{$row[Category]}</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of the quotes just like you would a bracket or an html tag. When you open one, you are inside until you close it. In this case, you needs quotes to tell php what to echo out and different quotes that will print for html attributes. It's usually easier to use single quotes for the php echo commands and double quotes for the html code. Then the `.` just means to stitch a bunch of stuff together without having to put the echo command ten times in a row. So when you have this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row[Category].'">'.$row[Category].'</option>';
```

you can break it down like this (just for your mental clarity, don't actually code this):

```
echo 
    '<option value=" '
    .
    $row[Category]
    .
    ' "> '
    .
    $row[Category]
    .
    '</option>'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes & Just insure the value of $row['Category']
Try it:
echo "".$row['Category']."";